# In Group Version-How to convert Custom Object Record into Opportunity

Tags: custom-object, administration

My company recently bought five licenses of Salesforce for Group Version. We now have a problem about uploading all the opportunity information we got in the excel file. Since we are in Group Version, there is no function for us to import opportunities and the third APP that mentioned in the community won't allow us to do it either. So I was thinking about uploading the file through Custom object and converting into Opportunity.

Is this possible? 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

"The limitation on triggers in Group Edition is intended that the org itself cannot create triggers.  The 'exception' is that you are still able to deploy packages from the AppExchange to extend your functionality.  You would need to go through the same  process of writing a managed package, submitting and paying for the security review, posting it on the AppExchange as any other AppExchange vendor." Above comment was picked from the URL below, see if that helps.
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008rRMIAY